# django - Refresh jwt in django restframework jwt

Tags: django, jwt

from http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token

> Each time the user loads the page, you can check if there is an existing non-expired token and if it's close to being expired, refresh it to extend their session. In other words, if a user is actively using your site, they can keep their "session" alive.

Can anyone explain to me how we can implement client-side like that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your expiration time delta and set it in your Django settings and client-side code.
2. Authorize to your app, you should receive valid token.
3. Store that token and current timestamp in localStorage.
4. Then on each page loading (or with setInterval schedule) check if delta between that timestamp and now (use moment.js for that) is closing to expiration value and refresh token if required.
5. If token refreshing passed well repeat step 3 and 4.